# Save scroll position in listview with tiles that have dynamic height images

Tags: flutter

When I navigate from my listview to a different view and then pop back, the position of the listview doesn't save. It redirects me to a different tile. If theres a set height to the tile, the navigation back is flawless so I've tried saving the height of the images using a future imageinfo and then setting the height of each tile to the imageinfo height but the scroll position still doesn't save.

any ideas brethrens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add ScrollController and make sure that your variable for your position is globally initialized

//variable.dart

```
double listviewPosition = 0.0;
```

//your_working_page.dart

```
ScrollController _listControl = new ScrollController();
void _scrollListener(){
  setState((){
    listviewPosition = _listControl.position.pixels;
  });
}
@override
void initState(){
  super.initState();
  _listControl.jumpTo(listviewPosition);
}

Widget build(BuildContext context){
  return Scaffold(
    body: Container(
      width: screen_width,
      height: screen_height,
      child: ListView(
        controller: _listControl,
        children: <Widget>[
          your_children here
        ]
      )
    )
  );
}
```

note: You can change listview to listview.builder if you want

Comment: how does _scrollListener() get called?

Answer (score -1):

There is a special Flutter object for that, it's called [PageStorageKey](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/PageStorageKey-class.html). It is not a widget, it's a `Key`. Since `Key`s are not as common as widgets and they can be tricky to use, I recommend you watch [this introduction to Keys by the Flutter team](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kn0EOS-ZiIc) first.

Once you understand what a `Key` is and what are they for, what you need is simply to add a unique `PageStorageKey` to your scrollable view, and the scroll position should be saved automatically.

Check out this snippet a wrote to showcase its usage. You can run it directly on [DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/b6409e10de32b280b8938aa75364fa7b) to see how it looks like:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTabController(
      length: 2,
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(widget.title),
          bottom: TabBar(
            tabs: [
              Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.looks_one), text: "List1"),
              Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.looks_two), text: "List2"),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        body: TabBarView(
          children: [
            _buildList(key: "key1", string: "List1: "),
            _buildList(key: "key2", string: "List2: "),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildList({String key, String string}) {
    return ListView.builder(
      key: PageStorageKey(key),
      itemBuilder: (_, i) => ListTile(title: Text("$string $i")),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: does this work with scoped models? my architecture uses mostly all stateless widgets and also im not going from tab bar to tabbar, im going from list tile to widget then back